# How to get the email id from people picker field using CSOM in SP 2010 Custom List Form

Tags: custom-list, spservices, user-profile-property

I have written the below code for getting the display name from the PeoplePicker field on PreSaveAction() call in my custom list form in SP 2010.

I got the displaytetx attr: mydomain\name2
Now  using this display name, how to get the email id, department etc from user profile? Something like, i can pass this as a param to some other API - CSOM / JSOM /SPServices which extracts the email id

```
          <script language="javascript" src="/project/AssetsLib/jquery-
           1.6.0.min.js" 
         type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script language="javascript" 
       src="/project/AssetsLib/SPUtility.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
             <script language="javascript" 
           src="/project/AssetsLib/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js" 
          type="text/javascript">
        </script>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   // This function from SPServices gets all of the Query String 
            //parameters
          var myuserid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
         var queryStringVals = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();

  var  whatDisplayName ="Reporting Manager Name";
    var pp2 = $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({  
        peoplePickerDisplayName: 
     whatDisplayName }).row.find("div[id='divEntityData']")
     .attr("displaytext");
    alert(  'the pp title ...' + pp);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help but I am using this code in a SP Online.

```
var strFieldName = "FieldName";  
var ppDiv= $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + strFieldName + "']");  
var spPP = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv[0].id];  
spPP.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);  
if (!spPP.HasInputError)   
           {  
             var userKeys = spPP.GetAllUserInfo();  
         var myUser = userKeys[0];  
           }  
alert(myUser.EntityData.SPUserID);
```

Regards,
Christophe

Comment: i think,SPClientPeoplePicker doesn't exist in SP 2010.Its available for SP 2013 only.

Comment: is there a way we can read the peoplepicker value using CSOM/JSOM? whats the API for that, any idea?

Comment: myUser.EntityData.SPUserID in this statement "SPUserID" does not exist